# Composer diagnose returns an error with OpenSSL library that I cannot figure out

Tags: php, macos, openssl, composer-php

When running `composer diagnose` I get the message:

The OpenSSL library (0.9.8y) used by PHP does not support TLSv1.2 or TLSv1.1.
If possible you should upgrade OpenSSL to version 1.0.1 or above.

I have searched for the solution, updated everything, changed the PATH when I had to... Everything seems to be OK but that error message is still there.
(I am trying to create a Laravel project.)

Does anyone know what I could/should try to make it work ?

Here are the info that might be useful to answer:

`php --version` => PHP 7.4.0 (cli) (built: Dec  2 2019 15:07:44) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.4.0, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.4.0, Copyright (c), by Zend Technologies

`composer --version` => Composer version 1.9.1 2019-11-01 17:20:17

`openssl version` => OpenSSL 1.1.1d  10 Sep 2019

`php -r "print_r(openssl_get_cert_locations());"` =>

> Array (
>
> ```
> [default_cert_file] => /usr/local/etc/openssl@1.1/cert.pem
>
> [default_cert_file_env] => SSL_CERT_FILE
>
> [default_cert_dir] => /usr/local/etc/openssl@1.1/certs
>
> [default_cert_dir_env] => SSL_CERT_DIR
>
> [default_private_dir] => /usr/local/etc/openssl@1.1/private
>
> [default_default_cert_area] => /usr/local/etc/openssl@1.1
>
> [ini_cafile] => /usr/local/etc/openssl@1.1/cert.pem
>
> [ini_capath] => /usr/local/etc/openssl@1.1/certs
> ```
>
> )

I work on macOS Sierra 10.12.6